# Add the product thumbnail on Woocommerce Thankyou page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, orders

In woocommerce, on Order received page (Thankyou page) the product image is not displayed in the order items.

How can I display the product image in order items on Order received page? 
Is there a usable hook for that? 
Or do I have to override the template `order/order-details-item.php` file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm looking for this since yesterday.
I've attempted many times still no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To display the thumbnail image in the order items on Order received page (thankyou), you will use:

```
// Display the product thumbnail in order received page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'order_received_item_thumbnail_image', 10, 3 );
function order_received_item_thumbnail_image( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting order received page only
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return $item_name;

    // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 ){
        $product_image = '<span style="float:left;display:block;width:56px;">' . $product->get_image(array(48, 48)) . '</span>';
        $item_name = $product_image . $item_name;
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: I tried modifying your code to account for both the order-pay and order-received endpoints, but didn't get it to work. Is there something i'm missing?

    `if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') || ! is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return $item_name;`

Comment: @David Yes there is problem in your if statement as you are using || operator so in any of the case mentioned in the if condition and it will return.
1. If it is order-pay then it wont be order-received ever.
2. If it is order-received then it wont be order-pay ever.

To make it work for both the conditions please use && operator so that it will only return from this method when endpoint is none of the both order-pay and order-received.